# Manually write entities from existing database

Tags: entity-framework

We have a very large stablished database (PostgreSQL for the matter) that suffers from standardization and I'd like to use Entity Framework in our future-to-be ASP.NET MVC application.

Is there a way to manually write Entities mappings?

I **really** don't want to autogenerate Entities based on Database First approach. And I don't have the option, for now, to migrate/update our schema.

Thank you.

**Edit**: after some more thinking we decided using NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate for the mappings.

Comment: Yes, you can manually write entities, but the edmx designer will probably save you a lot of time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx I believe POCO, Plain Old C# Objects, is what you're referring to.

Comment: You can also write mappings manually with "*Entity Framework Code First*" (<-- google search term).

Comment: Why don't you want to generate entities? If you already have a database this might be a good option.

Comment: I´ll take a look at the link provided and search for the terms specified. Thank you guys.

@usr: It's just a matter of preference, I don´t like auto-generated stuff.

Comment: You can also try using EF Power Tools to create POCO entities from your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate for mappings.